# Why running kill in linux needs sudo access

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo, kill

On one server(my development desktop), I am able to execute `kill` command without sudo, but on the other one, I will got `kill: kill 1 failed: operation not permitted`.

I assume that `kill` command will execute `/usr/bin/kill`.

When I check the permission of the file on both server, it shows the same for permission part as `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root`, which means that every user have read, write and execute permission of this file. Then why I need to do `sudo` on the other server? I am curious about which part between the two server makes this difference.

Answer (score 5):

The error message `kill: kill 1 failed: operation not permitted` states that it comes from the `kill` command, not the shell which tried to execute it. Otherwise you would see a message like `bash: /usr/bin/kill: Permission denied` (which is headed by "bash").

Instead ask yourself which process you tried to kill, and who is the user running said process. You cannot kill other people's processes as a restricted user, and the `kill` command itself will tell you it is not allowed to do so...